# Is there a way to remove limits from DML/DDL restrictions on a Reader Account in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to create a Reader Account in order to share data with an external party, that doesn't have the same DML/DDL restrictions that typical Reader Accounts do, thereby allowing the party to whom the data was shared to upload supplemental data files onto the Reader Account for enhanced analysis?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to create a reader account without DML restrictions.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html#what-is-restricted-allowed-in-a-reader-account

If you want to enable your clients add/modify data, you can create regular users which has limited access to the existing warehouses/databases/schemas and share login information of this users.

You can also use resource monitors to avoid unexpected credit usage caused by running warehouses which shared by your clients.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/resource-monitors.html